# Regex split by quotation and plus sign

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am trying to split a text from a textbox using some characters as operators. I have a grouping operator (") and a "AND" operator (+), pretty much like google does. So, this text:

```
box +box +"box" "box" "is.a.box" +"is.a.box" +"is a box"
```

In the textbox is returning this:

```
myArray[0] = box
myArray[1] = +box
myArray[2] = +
myArray[3] = "box"
myArray[4] = "box"
myArray[5] = "is.a.box"
myArray[6] = +
myArray[7] = "is.a.box"
myArray[8] = +
myArray[9] = "is a box"
```

Instead I want it to return this:

```
myArray[0] = box
myArray[1] = +box
myArray[2] = +"box"
myArray[3] = "box"
myArray[4] = "is.a.box"
myArray[5] = +"is.a.box"
myArray[6] = +"is a box"
```

This is the regexp I'm using:

```
/[\+\w]+|"[^"]+"/g
```

How can I split by " and + symbols together?

Comment: Why don't you just split by `space`?

Comment: What's expected behaviour for fringe cases such as text that contains '+' or '"', or is that not to be considered? I.e. is "box+box" to be turned in to "box", +"box", or just stay as "box+box", or something else?

Comment: @sp00m because that would split `"is a box"`

Comment: @sp00m The fact that he's using '"'s around some of the text would suggest that he may allow spaces as part of strings, even if his example strings don't contain them.

Comment: @Thor84no it should allow any unescaped character to be inside quotations, I put an example with a ".", but could be an space, a \,etc...

Comment: @EugenioCuevas what about his second question? what happens to `box+box` (outside of quotation marks)

Comment: @m.buettner `box+box` should be splitted to `box` and `+box`

Comment: @EugenioCuevas alright, have a look at my answer then

Comment: Personally I would say that if you want to treat quoted text as an entity all of it's own (no processing on the contents, potential for escaped quotes), then `String.split` is not the right approach. Regular expressions are just not well equipped to deal with the complexities this brings up and is often used inappropriately and with unforeseen consequences in such cases. Correctly parsing a string like that requires more advanced language parsing, even if it's just manually extracting strings one by one and putting them in to a `List`. Of course, the limitations might be ok for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
str.match(/\+?(?:"[^"]*"|[^\s+]+)/g)
```

That will start with a `+` if possible. Then it will try to match a `"`. If it can, it will take as many non-`"` characters as possible and the final `"`. If there is no `"` it will just take in as many non-space, non-`+` characters as possible.

This is pretty much what you had, except that I took out an optional `+` in front of both possible cases.

One more addition. If `box"box"` should result in two match `box` and `"box"` use this:

```
str.match(/\+?(?:"[^"]*"|[^\s+"]+)/g)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/\+?("[^"]*"|[^\s+])+/g
```

The trick is to treat quoted strings as if they were single characters. We look non-whitespace, non-special characters (`[^\s+]`), but we'll also pretend that quoted strings (`"[^"]*"`) are one character.

```
> 'box +box +"box" "box" "is.a.box" +"is.a.box"'.match(/\+?("[^"]*"|[^\s+])+/g)
  ["box", "+box", "+"box"", ""box"", ""is.a.box"", "+"is.a.box""]

> '"string with spaces" +"extended phrase"'.match(/\+?("[^"]*"|[^\s+])+/g)
  [""string with spaces"", "+"extended phrase""]

> 'box+box'.match(/\+?("[^"]*"|[^\s+])+/g)
  ["box", "+box"]
```

Comment: You are aware that you just changed around the order of your alternation so that the regex is not **exactly** the same as mine? ;)

Comment: @m.buettner Hehe, wow, yeah. I'm just trying to keep up with the morphing requirements. :P

Comment: yeah, me too, to be honest :D

Comment: Both solutions work like a charm, but @m.buettner is shorter in points, so I'll +1 this and accept his. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The result you want can be achieved with a simple split on spaces.

You might want to make it a little smarter and collapse multiple whitespace using the following:

```
myArray = str.split(/[\s]+/g)
```

For your input string, this returns the array you wanted:

```
["box", "+box", "+"box"", ""box"", ""is.a.box"", "+"is.a.box""]
```

Comment: That was initially true, but the asker has since added an example that shows quote-enclosed terms containing spaces.

Comment: Aah, the question changed regarding whitespace in quotes. m.buettner's answer is better.